# Sort NSArray of dictionaries with different keys by those keys, not by the values

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to sort an `NSArray` containing `NSDictionary`s. Each `NSDictionary` has one key-value pair, and the keys of each are different. I want the array sorted alphabetically by the keys, not by the values.

For example: [{ tyi = tyiopkh }, { asd = asdfgh; }, { bhf = bhffghj }, { try = tryu; }] should be sorted [{asd = asdfgh}, {bhf = bhffghj}, {try = tryu}, {tyi = tyiopkh}]

Comment: Do you want the array sorted by the keys of the dictionaries or the values of the dictionaries? Do all of the dictionaries have just one key/value pair?

Comment: If you have differents keys you have not the same kind of dictionary. I guess you have the same kind of dictionary with the same keys and you want to order it by one of their keys, right?

Comment: I want the array sorted by the keys of the dictionaries. Yes, all of the dictionaries inside array have just single key-value pair.

Comment: each dictionary has single key-value pair. each key is a variable so different from another dictionary of array

Comment: i have used NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myString forKey:aString]; to create a dictionary and then added each dictionary in an array. now want to sort dictionaries inside array using alphabetical order of key of each dictionary

Comment: The keys are strings? Are the values strings? Your example has all the keys being prefixes of their values. Is that the case for your real data? Why are these data in separate dictionaries in the first place? Since the keys are unique, why not one dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [NSDictionary allKeys] to get an array of keys and then can sort it using NSSortDescriptor

Comment: That will sort only keys. I want result in this order: { asd = asdfgh; }, { bhf = bhffghj; }, { try = tryu; }, { tyi = tyiopkh; })

Comment: i want to sort dictionaries inside array. not only keys

Comment: @iamPenquin you want to sort dictionary on basis of keys right ?

Comment: It's done. Thank you guys so much for your help. Please let me know if you guys have any questions.